# Does $P[X_j\in I_n]=0$ imply that $\delta_{X_j}(I_n)=0$?

Tags: probability-theory

Does $$P[X_j\in I_n]=F(I_n)=0, j=1,...n$$
imply that
$$\hat F_n(I_n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\delta_{X_i}(I_n)=0$$,
here $I_n$ are open intervals $(a_n,b_n)$ on which $F(a_n)=F(b_n)$ and $\delta _X$ denotes the dirac measure.

What if we have that $X_j\in I_n$ for a countable number of $\omega$; then the measure of the set would be zero, right? But but $\delta _{X_j}(I_n)$ would equal 1. Is something wrong with my reasoning?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $E[\hat F_n(A)]=\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nF_k(A)$ and that $\hat F_n(A)\geqslant0$ almost surely. Hence, if $F_n(A)=0$ for every $n$, then $\hat F_n(A)=0$ *almost surely*. Thus, $\delta_{X_n}(A)=n\hat F_n(A)-(n-1)\hat F_{n-1}(A)=0$ *almost surely*, for every $n$.

(Of course, this does not prevent $\delta_{X_n}(A)(\omega)=\mathbf 1_{X_n(\omega)\in A}$ to be nonzero for some $\omega$ in $\Omega$ and some $n$ but these $\omega$ would be exceptional in the sense that the set $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid\exists n,\,X_n(\omega)\in A\}$ has measure zero.)